# How to set conditions on "through" model defined by "hasManyThrough" relation in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I defined 3 models in Loopback: `job`, `contact` and `job_contact`(through model) and using `hasManyThrough` relations defined below relation:

> `job` has many `contact` through `job_contact`.

and I used the code below to find `contacts` by `job` through `job_contact`

```
job.findById(id, {
   include: {
       relation:'contact',
       where :{deleted: false},   // no working here
       scope:{
         where:{deleted: false}   // here will add condition on contact table
       }
   } 

})
```

Someone got any ideas? How can I put conditions on "through" model, `job_contact` model, in this case?

Comment: `hasManyThrough` relation is a many-to-many relation. So, does `contact` has many `job`?

Comment: right, it's many-to-many relation and contact does has many job, I'm trying to explain my problem in "loopback" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it is not possible to interact with the through model with filters on queries the two other models. If you want to access the through model you need to query it independently.

See part More Info at the bottom of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256741/set-the-custom-properties-in-joining-model-using-loopbacks-hasmanythrough) and the linked github discussion.

Comment: thanks for your answer, seems loopback doesn't have this feature.

Comment: @WeiLiang you cannot do job_contact.find({jobId: 1. contactId: 1}).then(...)?

Comment: I'm not using promises in loopback, but I have implements this function using async(make several calls). Using promises would be a good idea, but loopback support for promise is [not complete](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+promises) yet.